# How to make Split not add a newline at the end of each element

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split

```
$var="The quick brown fox"
$words = $var.Split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]::None)
echo $words[0] $words[2]
```

The output of this program is

```
The
brown
```

Why does `.Split()` add a newline at the end of each element of the output?
How can I prevent this?

I want the output to be

```
The brown
```

Comment: FWIW array index selectors are handy: `echo ($words[0,2] -join ' ')` especially for more than two elements.

Comment: An important point, which was only mentioned in passing in one of the answers, is that the PowerShell way to do the actual split is just `$words = -split $var`. No need to invoke the .NET Split method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `echo` (alias for `Write-Output`) which 'adds' it which you can see if you modify it to

```
echo ($words[0] + " " + $words[2])
```

which will result in

```
The brown
```

What is essentially happening is that you output 2 objects down the pipeline (strings) which get displayed each in an own line

If you just want to print out something without putting it to the pipeline you can use

```
Write-Host $words[0] $words[2]
```

Comment: You are correct - but I don't understand - what is $($words[0]) - why 2$? why a ()? And if I remove the double quotes from your statement - again it goes into different lines

Comment: @user93353 It's a sub expression to be sure the array element portion is understood and not considered part of the string. Subexpressions are denoted by `$()`

Comment: @Matt thanks for the explanation. However I updated my answer as I think a plain `+` is more readable in this case :)

Comment: It all depends on what the OP wants to do. Subexpressions can be very useful for longer strings. Could also use the format operator...... endless possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does .Split() add a newline at the end of each element of the output?

Because it creates string array if used against text:

> When using Split() against a text file or the string output of a command, you are dealing with an array. PowerShell automatically converts each line of the text file to an element of the array.

(from [SS64](http://ss64.com/ps/split.html))

The only way to create single string from string array - is to join them:

```
$words = $var.Split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]::None) -join ' ' # joining symbol
```

BTW space/newline/tab are default split symbols. So you can simplify your code a little:

```
$words = $var.Split() -join ' '
```

Comment: Depending how you read this it is like you are suggesting the Split is responsible for the new lines. It is not of course. This is fine approach on dealing with it but the root problem is not the split but how the OP is outputting.

Comment: @Matt These are not "new line" symbols or something. These are separate strings displayed on a new line each in PS console.

Comment: I know that... the op already _thinks_ its splits fault and that new lines are being added. It is not, which was my point.

Answer (score 0):

Split is not putting the newlines in, its the default output formatting because each object passed to echo is written separately.  A compact way of joining the words is to use interpolation of an array expression inside double-quotes.

```
echo "$($words[0,2])"
```

Such an interpolated array expression is joined using the value of variable `$OFS`, which by default is a space.

P.S.  You don't really even need the `echo` command, just putting the quoted string on a line by its self will result in it's output.

For fun, here's a one-liner that does what you want, without needing the variable `$words`:

```
"$((-split $var)[0,2])"
```